# why I can't keep observable alive after .onError() even I already use error handling like .catchError() onRxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

So, I want to keep the observable keep alive (not disposhed) even after input `onError()`, so I can input `onNext()`

I already follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885108/rxswift-error-handle-issue)

by adding `.catchError()` or `.catchErrorReturn()` but it didn't work like I expected

(nb: I run this code on playground)

```
    let bag = DisposeBag()
    let data = PublishSubject<Observable<Int>>()
    data.debug("debug").flatMap({
        $0.map({data in
            return data
        }).catchError({err in
            return Observable.empty()
        })
    }).subscribe(onNext:{
        print($0)
    },onCompleted:{
        print("end")
    }).disposed(by: bag)
    let inputData = PublishSubject<Int>()
    data.onNext(inputData)
    inputData.onNext(1)
    inputData.onNext(2)
    inputData.onError(MyError.anError)
    inputData.onNext(2)
```

actual result I get

```
1
2
```

expected result I want

```
1
2
2
```

Comment: How do you use `catchError` or `catchErrorReturn` exactly?

Comment: `onError` terminates the subscription. It's a basic principle of RX.

Comment: @AuRis so, there is no other way to make ```onError``` not terminating the subscription?

Comment: `onError` always terminates the subscription . You can choose to resubscribe in various ways, such as `retry`, or return a new publisher in a `catch` block. Refer to this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#error-handling

Comment: If you catch error and process it properly, you should not get `onError`, thus not ending subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you push an error into your `inputData` it is done and will no longer emit anything. (full stop) That is the Observable contract and catching the error from a different Observable doesn't change that.

Learn more about the [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) which says in part:

> Upon issuing an OnCompleted or OnError notification, *it may not thereafter issue any further notifications*.

[stress is mine]

---

As I mentioned in the comments: *That* observable will no longer be able to emit anything and any subscriptions on it will be disposed. However, the only subscription on it is from inside the flatMap. Your data subject will still be able to emit more.

for example:

```
let bag = DisposeBag()
let data = PublishSubject<Observable<Int>>()

data
    .debug("debug")
    .flatMap {
        $0.catchError { _ in Observable.empty() }
    }
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { print($0) },
        onCompleted: { print("end") }
    )
    .disposed(by: bag)

let inputData1 = PublishSubject<Int>()

data.onNext(inputData1)
inputData1.onNext(1)
inputData1.onNext(2)
inputData1.onError(MyError.anError)

let inputData2 = PublishSubject<Int>()
data.onNext(inputData2)
inputData2.onNext(2)
```

Will print out:

```
debug -> subscribed
debug -> Event next(RxSwift.PublishSubject<Swift.Int>)
1
2
debug -> Event next(RxSwift.PublishSubject<Swift.Int>)
2
```

Comment: Btw, why don't you provide some link which explains such a behavior of `PublishSubject`

Comment: Thanks. I've thought that it would be a good idea to provide in the answer, not in comments (:

Comment: Says the guy who doesn't answer questions. :-)

Comment: It takes a lot of time to write a good detailed answer.... And I'm at work so don't have much free time (^

Comment: @DanielT. so, it's cause by ```onError``` behavior that cause the observable no longger emit anything (disposhed)?

Comment: Yes *that* observable will no longer be able to emit anything and any subscriptions on it will be disposed. However, the only subscription on it is from _inside_ the flatMap. Your `data` subject will still be able to emit more.

Comment: @DanielT. thank you, finaly I'm understand right now.

Answer (score 1):

For the best solution, I would suggest using `materialize()` with `compactMap`.
take a look at https://michaellong.medium.com/rxswift-better-error-handling-with-compactmap-48a5d314d0f1